# Execution of Robot test case is not ending when sleep of 300seconds is added in test case

Tags: robotframework

There is a 300 second wait time in the test case during which the test execution do not communicate with the target and wait for the session to timeout.

```
Robot Test Case
    [Documentation]  Test case to verify the session timeout
    [Tag]  session-timeout
    [Timeout]  900 seconds
    [Teardown]  Disconnect And Unregister If Session Exist

    Register With Target
    Connect
    ...
    Sleep  300s  Wait for session timeout
    Verify Session Unregistered
```

But when I tried running my test case from pycharm the test execution is not ending even after all test steps are executed.
When I tried reducing the 300 seconds delay to 200 seconds the test case execution ends after all the test steps are executed.

I even tried with "Terminate All Processes" in the Suite Teardown. But still the test process is not ending. 
Any advise would be of great help!

Comment: Is the Robot Framework log file created? If so, then the test has concluded, but perhaps the process might be stuck.

Comment: Yes the log file gets created every time. But the process is not ending.

Comment: How do you start your test.

Comment: Using Run/Debug configuration setting in pycharm, The attachment of the configuration as shown below.

Comment: I could not attach the configuration settings. But the settings are as listed below.

Comment: When you start your test manually from the command line, do you observe the same results?

Comment: Module name : robot.run

Comment: Yes, I observe the same (test process never ending) when I ran from the command line.

Comment: Does it eventually lead to an error?

Comment: No, the test process never ends and so no error even after hours together.